# Trying to make build rules to create accessor class to resx file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, class, build, c++-cli, accessor

I have resources.resx file in my C++/CLI project and want to create a build to to automatically build an accessor class to help access the resources when needed. I have searched a lot but haven't found a decent solution yet (using vs2010).

I can create the accessor class with this:

resgen /str:c++ resources.resx

This creates a resources.h file (which I want) and a resources.resources file (which I can delete). But I'd like to have the command being run whenever I change the resources.resx file and this gives me some headache as the file already has a build target, "Managed resource compiler", and while it runs resgen on that file, it includes 7 other resources files and doesn't have the /str switch.

The only automatic solution so far is to make a pre-build event command but that means recompiling the whole project every single time I make a build.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue like this. In the Pre-Build Event of the project I inserted this:

```
resgen /str:c++,myApp,resources,resources.h.new resources.resx myApp.resources.resources
del myApp.resources.resources
fc /b resources.h resources.h.new > NUL:
if NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" ( type resources.h.new > resources.h )
del resources.h.new
```

Basically, I create a new resources.h and compare it with the existing file. If there are any differences, I use type to copy the file in order to update the timestamp. This make the build engine only update resources.h when it is needed. Not pretty, but it gets the job done.